# Is there a way of implementing the auto keyword for C++03

Tags: c++

In C++03 or earlier, is there a way of implementing the `auto` keyword? Not an object class, but so that it can be used like this [C++11]

```
auto x = 5;
std::cout << x;
```

I quickly 'whipped up' an implementation, but it is pretty rubbish, as you can cast it to any type - too much like an `object` class, and pretty basic, I know, but anyway, here it is:

```
class auto_t
{
public:
    template < typename _Ty > auto_t(const _Ty &_Value)
        : __data(_Value)
    {
    }

    template < typename _Ty >  operator _Ty()
    {
        return (_Ty)__data;
    }
private:
    void *__data;
};

#define auto auto_t
```

Comment: If using a particular compiler, why don't you take advantage of an extension (e.g. GCC's `__typeof`)?

Comment: The closest (but far away) into that direction is boost::foreach, I think.

Comment: Strange that it did not occur to you to use a C++11 compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to emulate the C++11 auto functionality with the same syntax. The code you supplied introduces a new type that just attempts to wrap your original type (ignoring the fact that it doesn't actually retain the the original object's lifetime). However, this new type will **not** follow the same rules for argument dependent lookup and type conversions as your original type. The auto keyword in C++11 is a language feature not a library extension. The best you could do to emulate it is with a MACRO like the [boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/typeof/refe.html#typeof.auto) does.

Comment: Consider changing the url to `http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/typeof/refe.html#typeof.auto` to reflect the latest version.

Comment: @remyabel or even: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/typeof/refe.html#typeof.typo

Answer (score 3):

Not really. That's why C++11 introduces it as a keyword, and not a library feature.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of any way doing what you want other than writing a compiler that inspects the intended type and creates the appropriate code for you.

That is a language feature and hence implemented by compilers.